# How to remove or subset samples based upon two different columns in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a df with 1000s of rows. Simplified it looks like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Sample = c('A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'A1', 'B2', 'C3','A1', 'B2', 'C3'),
                  Day = c('1', '3', '5', '4', '2', '6','5', '4', '2' ),
                  Value = c('0.1', '0.8', '0.7', '0.6', '0.3', '0.4', '0.4', '0.2', '0.3'))
```

I want to remove samples which occur on days after the max value was measured.

I can look at the max value and which days they fall on for each sample:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>% 
             group_by(Value, Day, Sample) %>%
             slice(which.max(Value))
```

Then if I could remove rows for each sample which occurs on days after the maximum was measured I'd have the desired df:

```
df3 <- data.frame(Sample = c('A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'A1', 'B2', 'C3'),
                                    Day = c('1', '3', '5', '4', '2','2' ),
                                    Value = c('0.1', '0.8', '0.7', '0.6', '0.3', '0.3'))
```

This seems like it needs a for-loop, but I'm not firing on many cylinders today, so any help is much appreciated. TIA.

Comment: @akrun thank you for catching that, C3  - 6 - 0.4 should not be there. I will edit df3.

Comment: can you check the solution posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example data was created with numeric columns as `character` (note the `'0.1'` instead of just `0.1`), so we use `type.convert` to automatically convert the column types, `arrange` the data by 'Sample', 'Day', then grouped by 'Sample', get the index of max value of 'Value', add 1 and remove (`-`) the row with `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
     arrange(Sample, Day) %>% 
     group_by(Sample) %>%
     slice(-(which.max(Value) + 1)) %>%
     ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Sample   Day Value
  <chr>  <int> <dbl>
1 A1         1   0.1
2 A1         4   0.6
3 B2         2   0.3
4 B2         3   0.8
5 C3         2   0.3
6 C3         5   0.7
```

---

If we want to get rid of all rows after `max` (after `arrange`ing by 'Day', 'Sample')

```
df1 %>% 
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
     arrange(Sample, Day) %>%
     group_by(Sample) %>% 
     filter(cumsum(cumsum(Value == max(Value, na.rm = TRUE))) <= 1) %>%
     ungroup
```

Or use `slice` with `seq`

```
df1 %>%
     type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
     arrange(Sample, Day) %>% 
     group_by(Sample) %>%
     slice(seq(which.max(Value))) %>%
     ungroup
```

Comment: This would work great, except it only gets rid of samples the day after the max value, but not 2 or three days after the max value and so on. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @amwalker do you want get rid of all values after max

Comment: I used the slice with seq method and looks like it worked beautifully. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `ave` -

```
df1 <- type.convert(df1, as.is = TRUE)
df1 <- df1[with(df1, order(Sample, Day)), ]

subset(df1, as.logical(ave(Value, Sample, 
            FUN = function(x) seq_along(x) <= match(max(x), x))))

#  Sample Day Value
#1     A1   1   0.1
#4     A1   4   0.6
#5     B2   2   0.3
#2     B2   3   0.8
#9     C3   2   0.3
#3     C3   5   0.7
```